# How to make chapter first page use mystyle?

Tags: fancyhdr, etoolbox

It seems chapter first page use `plain` style. I created `mystyle`. How to make chapter first page to use `mystyle`?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

But wait. I want just chapter first page using it. The contents page and other which use `plain` should not be affected. So edit `plain` style is not an answer (let me know if I'm wrong).

Perhaps kind of

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{mystyle}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

is what I'm looking for. This unfurtunatelly/interestingly also affects the contents page (why?).

Comment: In [the `fancyhdr` documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) it says that the first page of a chapter always uses the `plain` style, so you need to override the `plain` style using `\fancypagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: Just added some important ending to the question, please consider it. The `plain` style is used in other parts of the document, so I don't want to touch it. Question is how to make chapter first page use another style instead of `plain`.

Comment: Your edit renders your question much more interesting, I'll upvote it now.  I was about to suggest using `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{}` from `etoolbox`, but it turns out that even then the table of contents also gets affected.  I guess `\tableofcontents` implicitly calls `\chapter` in a report?  I'll have to give more thought to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titles of pseudo chapters like the table of contents are set using `\chapter*`. If you do not need any unnumbered chapters yourself, we can patch `\chapter` to use `mystyle` and `\chapter*` to use `plain` using `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\makeatletter
    \patchcmd\chapter{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{}
    \pretocmd\@schapter{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

---

Following your comment, a better solution is probably to explicitly reset `\chapter`'s page style to `plain` only when desired.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\patchcmd\chapter{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{}
\def\makechapterpagestyleplain{%
    \patchcmd\chapter{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{%
        \GenericWarning{}{LaTeX Warning: Could not patch \string\chapter to use the page style `plain'.}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

{\makechapterpagestyleplain
\tableofcontents
}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this answer because is minimalist and hits the problem right in the head. The others are more comple(x/te). And I just realized what I need perhaps is not exaclty what I asked. Some special chapters (chapter*) actually need header (Contents should be `plain` but References should be `mystyle`).

Comment: @KcFnMi In that case you will probably want to reset the page style explicitly every time you don't want `mystyle`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments to your question, my first instinct to address your edited question is to issue `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{}`, but by inserting `\show\tableofcontents` in the document I've confirmed that in reports `\tableofcontents` uses the starred variant of `\chapter`, so merely patching `\chapter` still causes problems with pages you wish to keep plain.

One way to get around this would be to call `\apptocmd` on any special chapter-like non-chapter pages that should remain plain.  The problem with this approach is its ad hoc style:  if you decide later to add other chapter-like non-chapter pages, you would need to use `\apptocmd` on them too.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

If you knew you wouldn't need any other chapter-like non-chapter pages, this would be fine, but that assumption isn't likely to pertain considering that packages you use might introduce other such pages.  [As the other answer suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494625/189103), since `\tableofcontents` uses `\chapter*` specifically you could instead try patching that.  The upside is that this should affect all chapter-like non-chapter pages (unless any of them use the unstarred variant?), but the downside is that this assumes you won't need to use `\chapter*` yourself unless you're okay with unnumbered chapters keeping the `plain` page style.

Answer (score 1):

If only the first page of numbered chapters should use pagestyle `mystyle` you could patch `\@chapter`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    \pretocmd\@chapter{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\makeatletter
    \pretocmd\@chapter{\thispagestyle{mystyle}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter*{Starred Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Additional remark: Note that your definition of `mystyle` only adds its settings to the already active fancyheader settings. So only on the first pages of numbered chapters only the width of the headerule changes. `\thispagestyle{mystyle}` changes the fancyheader local and only on the current page. But if you would use `\pagestyle{mystyle}` in your document, then the change is global and you can *not reset* the header linewidth using `\pagestyle{fancy}`. If the changes should only be local, you have to use `\pagestyle{mystyle}` in a group.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
    \rhead{added by mystyle}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
{%
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
  \lipsum[1-9]
  \clearpage
}
\lipsum[1-9]

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\lipsum[1-9]
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```